# How to create mask with multiple alternative values (Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a Pandas DataFrame `f` defined as follows. I am trying to create a mask to select all rows with value 'a' or 'b' in column 'xx'(I would like to select out row 0, 1, 3, 4).

```
f = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b','c','a', 'b','c'],['1', '2','3', '4', '5','6', ]])
f = f.transpose()
f.columns = ['xx', 'yy']
f

   xx   yy
0   a   1
1   b   2
2   c   3
3   a   4
4   b   5
5   c   6
```

Is there any elegant way to do this in pandas? 
I know to select all rows with f.xx =='a', we can do f[f.xx == 'a']. While I have not figure out how to select rows with f.xx is either 'a' or 'b'. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
 print(f[(f["xx"].isin(("a","b")))])
```

Which will give you:

```
  xx yy
0  a  1
1  b  2
3  a  4
4  b  5
```

If you really wanted a mask you could use or `|`:

```
mask = (f["xx"] == "a") | (f["xx"] == "b")

print(f[mask])
```

Which will give you the same output:

```
 xx yy
0  a  1
1  b  2
3  a  4
4  b  5
```